# React Context update value from provider wrapping child

Tags: reactjs, react-context

This may be a simple problem with React Context, but I cant find a way to do what I need.

I have a component, which consumes some context:

```js
export const App = () => {
  const value = useContext(MyContext);

  return <ComponentA>{value}</ComponentA>;
};
```

The context is in a different module:

```js
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const MyContext = createContext("Default value");
```

Now, `ComponentA` has a child component, which wraps the children from `ComponentA`:

```js
const ComponentB = ({ children }) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

export const ComponentA: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value='Modified value'>
      <ComponentB>{children}</ComponentB>
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I expect the `text` to be updated, and `App` to render "Updated value"; but instead it renders "Default value".

Does anyone know why this happen? Here are two sandboxes, the first with the example above—https://codesandbox.io/s/dnd-kit-sortable-forked-cm2vnv— and the second trying to update the context with useState: https://codesandbox.io/s/dnd-kit-sortable-forked-e6vrhp

Answer (score 0):

Move the consumption of you context below the context provider.
In your example it should be in `ComponentB`

```
export const ComponentB = ({ children }) => {
  const value = useContext(MyContext);

  return (
    <>
      {value} — (should render «Updated value»)
      {children}
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit dnd-kit-sortable (forked)]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I need to use this `value` in the `App` component, I can not set it in the `children`